# Substitue for IN clause for AND conditions - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

We use `IN` clause to replace many `OR` conditions.
Like, can I have any other clause to replace many `AND` condition?

Comment: unfortuantely, no. [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: Hard to say.  Can you provide an example of what you are trying to replace?

Comment: @JW웃: What's the link between this question and relational division?

Comment: `WHERE foo IN (NULL)` will do the trick (always returns zero rows, like the query you propose).

Comment: @Andomar because in my own understanding he wants to get a record which a condition  is true for all, eg. `col = 1 AND col = 2 AND col = 3`.

Answer (score 1):

That would not make sense:

```
YourColumn AND_IN (1,2,3)
```

This would never be true, since a column cannot be two values at once.

Answer (score 1):

No,

Thats because one field won't be having multiple values.

for eg.

You would never write a query that says

```
SELECT * 
FROM
tblName
WHERE 
fldCol = 1
AND fldCol = 2
AND fldCol = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the alternative for this query,

```
SELECT  ID
FROM    TableName
WHERE   col = 1 AND col = 2 AND col = 3
```

which will give empty result set because a record can have only one value at a time. This should be written as:

```
SELECT  ID
FROM    TableName
WHERE   col IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP   BY ID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 3
```

[SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)